# Sandbox is preventing me from formatting a string

Tags: groovy, jenkins-workflow

I have a simple groovy script:

```
node ("master")
{
  echo "I am about to try to use String.format"
  def jjj = String.format("bob")
  echo jjj 
}
```

If I put this script right into my job configuration and run it, it runs fine.

But if I put that script into a file which I then load via "Workflow script from SCM", I get the error

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: unclassified staticMethod java.lang.String format java.lang.String
```

How do I work around this?  Is it possible to turn off the sandbox for "Workflow script from SCM" like it is for "Workflow script"?

Or is there some sandbox-approved way of formatting a string in groovy?

And why is it preventing me from formatting a string in the first place?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think it's not possible to disable sandboxing when using ***Workflow script from SCM***

However you can approve the usage here:

```
http://<jenkins_host>:<port>/scriptApproval/
```

Comment: There is nothing to approve when you get an `unclassified` error. That means a bug in the Script Security plugin.

Answer (score 3):

> How do I work around this?

Possibly (untested)

```
String.format("bob", [])
```

rather than using varargs. At any rate you should file a bug in JIRA (component `script-security-plugin`, label `workflow`) with steps to reproduce.

> Is it possible to turn off the sandbox for "Workflow script from SCM" like it is for "Workflow script"?

No: [JENKINS-28178](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28178)