# How to put JOB_NAME excluding folder into an environment variable in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to put the name of the currently executing Jenkins job into an environment variable for use later in my pipeline, without the folder name. I'm assuming I need something like :

```
withEnv(['JOB_BASE_NAME=JOB_NAME.split('/').last()']) {
    echo "Job base name: ${JOB_BASE_NAME}"
}
```

but I get an error:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: 
    unclassified method java.lang.String div java.lang.String
```

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33573568/sandbox-is-preventing-me-from-formatting-a-string) helps

Comment: Sorry for off-topic, but I wonder in which cases the `/` character does appear in Jenkins' `JOB_NAME`?

Comment: @Sasha : let me know if you find out

Comment: @markgalassi, it looks like I've found it out — I assume it's when you create a "folder" job and then create an actual job within (then URL looks like `http://myserver.com/job/MyFolder1/job/MyJob1` and job name looks like `MyFolder1/MyJob1`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I worked it out. In case anyone finds it useful:

```
def jobBaseName = "${env.JOB_NAME}".split('/').last()
echo "Job Name (excl. path): ${jobBaseName}"
```

Comment: No need to put the quotes or brackets around JOB_NAME: env.JOB_NAME.split('/').last()
Works just as well.  The variable returns a string already.

Answer (score 19):

In Jenkins documentation, you have the [§Using environment variables](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#using-environment-variables) section which mentions:

> The full list of environment variables accessible from within Jenkins Pipeline is documented at [localhost:8080/pipeline-syntax/globals#env](http://localhost:8080/pipeline-syntax/globals#env), assuming a Jenkins master is running on localhost:8080

If you follow the link you can find that `JOB_BASE_NAME` is already provided OOTB by Jenkins so this is exactly what you want.

> **`JOB_BASE_NAME`** - 
>   Short Name of the project of this build stripping off folder paths, such as "foo" for "bar/foo".

Comment: In multibranch `JOB_BASE_NAME` can be for example `PR-123`, so there are cases where this variable is no good.

Answer (score 0):

might be too late, but thought would help someone in need for a simpler solution using bash.

```
${JOB_NAME%%/*}
```

Example:

- I have a project created with name: `poc_jenkins_pipeline`
- If i try accessing default jenkins variable `${JOB_NAME}`

  - it returns value `poc_jenkins_pipeline/develop` i.e. `<project name>/<branch name>`
- By using % operator in bash `${JOB_NAME%%/*}` returns value `poc_jenkins_pipeline`
- Reference Link - https://qa.nuxeo.org/jenkins/pipeline-syntax/globals

Answer (score 0):

If you want the name of Jenkins job without the folder name you can use:

```
def job = "${JOB_BASE_NAME}"
```